# Не работает Firefox через geckodriver, если использовать отдельный профиль, выдает ошибку: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, jython

использую:

```
selenium server 3.0.1
firefox 46+, пробовал на разных версиях
Windows 10
Jython 2.5.4
```

Код:

```
self.profileDir = File(self.dict['profileDir'])
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", Config.DISTR_DIR + '\\geckodriver.exe')
self.profile = FirefoxProfile(self.profileDir)
self.driver = FirefoxDriver(self.profile)
```

При запуске выдает ошибку:

```
1479121081847   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:13582

self.driver = FirefoxDriver(self.profile)
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Дело в том, что если убрать подгрузку профиля, и сделать просто:

```
self.driver = FirefoxDriver()
```

то все вроде как хорошо, но мне надо обязательно профиль загрузить.
Пробовал увеличить память у Java (сейчас -Xms64M -Xmx512M) до -Xmx1200M (выше почему то java ругается), иногда все же браузер запускается, но это крайне редко и не стабильно.
Какие есть пути решения и с почему это происходит именно из за подгрузки профиля?

Comment: вообще ошибки говорит, что у тебя недостаточно памяти. Попробуй увеличить размер хипа для jvm. Для этого в аргументах jvm укажи: `java -Xmx1024m -Xms256m`

Comment: Пробовал не помогает, я писал в вопросе

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что браузер Firefox, в профиле, который я хотел подгрузить, закешировал 350 мб информации и при попытке его подгрузить, java видимо всю эту информацию глотала и валилась по выходу из рамок хипа. Очистив кеш в браузере проблема больше не повторяется!!!

Answer (score 0):

Что значит отдельный профиль? 
Установи ФФ 45

в найстройках пропиши

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C://Java       
libraries//Gecko//geckodriver.exe");  
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

И все будет работать

Comment: Мне не надо 45 версию мозилы, интересует именно 46+ версия, желательно вообще на последней. Отдельный профиль -  это значит я его подгружаю, как отдельный профиль браузера self.driver = FirefoxDriver(self.profile) я выше писал об этом